# How do I use compose in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

Im having problems using compose in Typescript....

```
const rawHeaders = R.compose(
  R.join('\n'),
  R.map(x=>`${x[0]}: ${x[1]}`),
  R.toPairs
)
```

I have tried the below, but it's brutal. Anyone know a way to make this work more elegantly?

```
const rawHeaders:Function = R.compose(
  R.join('\n'),
  R.map((x:[String, String]) =>`${x[0]}: ${x[1]}`),
  (x:{s:String})=>R.toPairs(x))
)
```

I have also tried to use ts-ignore, which at present seems to be the best option.

```
const rawHeaders = R.compose(
  R.join('\n'),
  // @ts-ignore
  R.map(x=>`${x[0]}: ${x[1]}`),
  // @ts-ignore
  R.toPairs
)
```

Comment: There are several TS typing files for Ramda out there, but, as I understand it, TS does not yet have the capability to handle some of the higher-order manipulations done by Ramda.  `compose` is probably top of the list.  But I don't know the details.

Comment: Thanks Scott, it makes no sense to use TypeScript in my opinion but I have don't have a choice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried leveraging the typing of compose itself? You can give it the arguments and the return values of each function in the compose like so:

```js
const rawHeaders = R.compose<
  { [key: string]: string | number }, // Argument
  Array<[string, string]>, // Return of toPairs
  string[], // Return of map
  string // Return of join
>(
  R.join('\n'),
  R.map(x => `${x[0]}: ${x[1]}`),
  R.toPairs
);
```

Personally I prefer to use `pipe` as the typings match up to the argument order within `pipe`, compared to `compose` which is backwards:

```js
const rawHeaders = R.pipe<
  { [key: string]: string | number }, //Argument
  Array<[string, string]>, // return of toPairs
  string[], // return of map
  string // return of join
>(
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(x => `${x[0]}: ${x[1]}`),
  R.join('\n')
);
```

Either way, each function in the pipe/compose gets the right value and you don't need to decorate the function within the pipe exclusively(unless you start using something like `R.flip`). It's verbose, but it works.

(you can specify as many args as you need for the first function, the overloads will handle the rest btw)

Comment: With your first (compose) example, I get an error on line 2: `Type '{ [key: string]: string | number; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.` I'm using @types/ramda 0.28.13. What did you use?